# How to use lapply to find closest value in a list in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the model-predicted value closest to a real observed value within a large dataframe. I believe I need to use lapply, but I'm really not sure. Thanks in advance, SE, and sorry if this is a repeat of a previous post, I looked.

```
df <- data.frame(pred = rnorm(50, mean = 100, sd = 10),
                 cand = I(replicate(50, exp = I(list(rnorm(6, mean = 100, sd = 10))))))
```

So far, I've come up with a 1-line function that works when run on a single row, but I have two problems:

```
df$closest <- sapply( df, function(x) { which.min( abs( df$pred[x] - df$cand[[x]] ) ) } )
```

1. This function won't work on the full list, probably because I am new to the apply family.
2. This function returns a list position, not the actual value, which is what I need.

   `Error in df$cand[[x]] : no such index at level 1`

Comment: You are looping over the columns instead of sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` allows us to operate on the rows, or the columns, because you are looking to loop through the rows, a margin of 1 (rows) should get the job done!

We could use `apply`:

```
df$closest <- apply( df,MARGIN = 1, function(x) { which.min( abs( x$pred - x$cand ) ) } )
```

Comment: I am reaccepting this answer over akrun's because, although they both work, this is more similar to the code I wrote as my example. Thanks both of you! I'm still just getting the list position instead of the value, but I think I can figure that out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can use `Map` instead of `sapply` because `sapply` loops over each of the columns and the `x` anonymous function value is the value of that column.  It cannot be used for indexing

```
df$closest <-  unlist(Map(function(x, y) which.min(abs(y - x)), df$pred, df$cand))
```

Or else with `sapply`, we have to loop over the row index